# why HTTP method delete and put considered idempotent?

Tags: rest, http

I read articles that says "all HTTP methods are idempotent except POST method".

I cannot understand that explanation.

In my opinion,
"Both PUT and DELETE change something on the server, so calling them repeatedly does not cause the same effect."

So, why are they(PUT, DELETE) considered idempotent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you `DELETE` something twice in a row, the overall effect is the same as if you had only deleted it once: The resource is gone.

If you upload (`PUT`) the same data under the same name twice, the effect is the same as if you had only uploaded it once.

Comment: thanks for your help. i apprecitate it. but can I ask one more question? i understood the PUT thing, but not the DELETE method. If I use POST method, I POST 2things, then two things are created. and If I use DELETE method, I DELETE 2things, then two things are deleted.. what are the differences?

Comment: and ofcourse can`t I delete the same data for twice..? like POST

Comment: @jwkoo If you do `DELETE /foo` and then `DELETE /foo` again, how does that delete two things? The first `DELETE` removes `/foo`, and then the second `DELETE` does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

May i answer to the question by extending the subject a bit?

You say PUT is considered idempotent, but what if there is a field, like a timestamp i.e. "LastUpdateTime" in the response?

If 2 exactly same updates are executed, the response will not be exactly the same... The First one will have a "LastUpdateTime" less than the Second.

So I believe, some verbs are cosidered to be idempotent, if you treat the implementation in a certain way.

**Short answer**: "it depends on your implementation"